# Bootstrap Radio button result

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, bootstrap-4

Based on below HTML snippet, manage to get two lines of radio button. When you click on the radio button on the first line, and then proceeds to click any of the radio button on the second line, the result of the radio button on the first line disappears.
How can I make sure, results of both lines of radio button appear together.

```
<!-- Start first Div -->
<div>
  
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3 (disabled)</label>
</div>

</div>
<!-- End first Div -->

<!-- Start second Div -->
<div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio4">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio5">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6">3 (disabled)</label>
</div>
  
</div>

<!-- End Second Div -->
```

Thanks

John

Comment: You need to use different name for second group. Radio button are grouped together using name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the MDN documentation on radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group
> the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio
> button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected
> radio button in the same group.

So, if you want the second `<div>` radio buttons to be separate, you have to use a different `name` for that set of buttons:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Start first Div -->
<div>

  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3 (disabled)</label>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End first Div -->

<!-- Start second Div -->
<div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions2" id="inlineRadio4" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio4">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions2" id="inlineRadio5" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio5">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions2" id="inlineRadio6" value="option3" disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6">3 (disabled)</label>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- End Second Div -->
```